# Fetching Magento thumbnail

Tags: php, image, magento, thumbnails

We have a quote page with the following code for fetching item information but we can't get the product image to show.

```
<tr>
  <td rowspan="<?php echo $mergedCells; ?>" class="cart-image"><img src="<?php echo $item->getProductThumbnail(); ?>" width="75" height="75"/></td>
  <td><?php echo $item->getName(); ?> <?php echo $item->getProductOptions(); ?><br />
    <?php echo $this->__('SKU:') ?> <?php echo $item->getSku(); ?></td>
  <td class="ItemQty"><?php echo $this->getItemQty($item); ?></td>
</tr>
```

Have tried a couple of different solutions but still getting the same result, would be great if anyone has a solution or an idea we can try.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`<?php $item = $this->getItem() ?>`

Try adding this before your `getProductThumbnail()` call.

You may also want to try:

`<img src="<?php echo $this->getProductThumbnail()->resize(50); ?>" alt="<?php echo $this->htmlEscape($this->getProductName()) ?>" /></a>`